# What is the length of paypal data?

Tags: paypal

I need to know what is the length of paypal data:

- Api login (I think this one is dynamic)
- Api password
- Api signature

I have searched in `paypal` documentation, but I do not find anything helpful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked in few of my PayPal accounts. Password and Signature are fixed length.

API password - 16 characters

API signature - 56 characters

Comment: Password which I've used In my application have 10 characters so something is wrong.

Comment: Sandbox uses 10 numbers only.

Answer (score 2):

The length for API password & signature varies from account to account.

View/create API signature for Live paypal account: [Login API](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run)

View/create API signature for sandbox paypal account: [Link](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run)